# drupal/core-composer-scaffold doesn't put core in web folder

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I'm trying to bring my drupal 8 composer.json up to date, and move from the old drupal-scaffold to core-composer-scaffold. But composer2 puts the core and related directories directly into the app folder, rather than app/web.

My composer.json contents are:

```
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal/clamav": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
        "drupal/core-dev": "^8.1",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.4.0",
        "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.1.0",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.9.0",
        "drupal/officialfacebookpixel": "^1.1",
        "drupal/php": "^1.0",
        "drupal/schema_metatag": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/sendgrid_integration": "^1.3",
        "drupal/simple_facebook_pixel": "1.1",
        "drupal/superfish": "^1.3.0",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5.0",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "discard-changes": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "enable-patching": true,
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            },
            "patches": [],
            "installer-types": [
                "bower-asset",
                "npm-asset"
            ],
            "installer-paths": {
                "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
                "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
                "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
                "web/modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
                "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
                "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-profile"],
                "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
                "web/themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"],
                "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                    "type:drupal-library",
                    "type:bower-asset",
                    "type:npm-asset"
                ]
            },
            "merge-plugin": {
                "include": [
                    "web/modules/custom/*/composer.json"
                ],
                "replace": false,
                "ignore-duplicates": true
            }
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "search-git-submodules": "find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name .git",
        "remove-git-submodules": "find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name .git | xargs rm -rf",
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@remove-git-submodules"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@remove-git-submodules"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with that myself, so why is this happening?2

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold#defining-project-locations), `web-root` should be `"./web"` instead of `"web/"`

```
"locations": {
  "web-root": "./web"
},
```

Comment: So I made that change. Unfortunately I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found the solution to my own problem.

In rare cases it matters what order you use in the required section.

I moved "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0" to the top of the list, and composer now puts everything in the right place.

The problem seems to occur because of specific project dependencies, which keep composer from reordering the installs for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to @Ken - for me, I was missing the following package which needed to be at the top of the required list:

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
```

Upon deleting `/vendor` and re-running `composer update`, the core folder was properly created.